# Appending data in a pagination reducer - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I just want to ask, if why my reducer keeps on overriding my nested data, even though value is an array. Basically what i'm building here is like a pagination. So far here's my code:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    data: [],
    page: 1
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_NEWS_SUCCESS: {
            return { 
                data : {
                    [action.payload.category]: [ action.payload.data ]
                },
                page: action.payload.page };
        }
    }

    return state;
}
```

The image below is the return data of my reducer, basically on the `echelon array` for the next state the `0` key should still be there and will append another set of data. But as you can see on the second red rectangle it overrides the previous `0` key.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You override existing array in these lines:

```
 data : {
     [action.payload.category]: [ action.payload.data ]
 },
```

You should append new object to existing array. You can use spread syntax to achieve it:

```
case GET_NEWS_SUCCESS: {
            if (!state.data[action.payload.category]) {
               state.data[action.payload.category] = [];
            }
            return { 
                data : {
                     [action.payload.category]: [ ...state.data[action.payload.category], action.payload.data ]
                },
                page: action.payload.page };
        }
```

Comment: I already tried this and it gives me an error of `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. Maybe because of this `...state.data[action.payload.category]` because the `action.payload.category` is not yet existing

Comment: So you have to check if it's defined before updating and if not initializing it with an empty array. Please see updated answer. If you already know all possible categories names you can initialize state with empty categories arrays instead of checking it on each update.

Comment: I'll try this, the category is not known since it is fetch from the api.

Comment: Looks like the page count is not resetting when the category changes. Is it okay to do  this `state.page` = 1 to reset the pager?

Comment: If you need to reset `page` property it's totally ok. It depends only on your requirements.

Comment: But maybe the state  `page` value should be set in action payload data? or maybe API call should return correct `page` value? It's hard to say because it actually depends on your application details and is not related to this SO question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137346/discussion-between-sydney-loteria-and-bartek-fryzowicz).